# Java if or statement not working as expected

Tags: java, if-statement

The or statement in the first line of my if statement is not working as i would expect it to, any suggestions?

```
if(answer == "deposit" || "Deposit"){
        System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit?");
        final int deposit = console.readInt();
        account.deposit(deposit);
        System.out.println( "This leaves you with $" + formatter.format(account.getBalance()) + " in your account");
    }else if(answer == "Check Balance"){
        System.out.println( "You have $" + formatter.format(account.getBalance()) + " in your account");
    }else if(answer == "Withdraw"){
        System.out.println("How much would you like to take out?");
        final int with = console.readInt();
        account.withdraw(with);
        System.out.println( "This leaves you with $" + formatter.format(account.getBalance()) + " in your account");
    }else{
        System.out.println("You didn't enter a correct term, please try again.");
    }
```

Comment: @Reimeus Sure, that's obviously part of it, but there's the whole trying to use two values and one comparison operator thing also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, logical-OR conditions don't work this way in Java like they do in English.  You must write it out explicitly.  Second, [don't use `==` to compare `String` values.  Use `equals()` for all `String` value comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

```
if ("deposit".equals(answer) || "Deposit".equals(answer))
```

Or you can use [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)).

```
if ("deposit".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the method 'equals' for string comparison. E.g. answer.equals("deposit").

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (answer.equals("deposit") || answer.equals("Deposit")) {`

and `}else if(answer.equals("Check Balance")){`

Answer (score 0):

Testing if strings are equal in Java should not be done with `==`, but with:

```
if ( answer.equals("Check Balance") )
```

With `==` you compare pointers of `String` objects, but `answer` and `"Check Balance"` are different object - second one is created during test so even if they have equal value, they are not identical. `equals` check only object's content.

Answer (score 0):

For String you need to use `String.equals` method

```
if("deposit".equals(answer)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(answer == "deposit" || "Deposit"){
```

as

```
if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("deposit")){
```

or

```
if (answer.equals("deposit") || answer.equals("Deposit")) {
```

*Reason*

`equals()` method is present in the `java.lang.Object` class and it is expected to check for the equivalence of the state of objects!. That means, the contents of the objects. Whereas the `==` operator is expected to check the actual object instances are same or not.

*Example*

Consider two different reference variables `str1` and `str2`

```
str1 = new String("abc");
str2 = new String("abc");
```

if you use the `equals()`

```
System.out.println((str1.equals(str2))?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

You will get the output as `TRUE`

if you use `==`

```
 System.out.println((str1==str2)?"TRUE":"FALSE");
```

Now you will get the `FALSE` as output because both `str1` and `str2` are pointing to two different objects even though both of them share the same string content. It is because of `new String()` everytime a new object is created.